# infinitely many distinct rational numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To prove: If $\dfrac{a}{b}$ is a rational number in reduced form, then there exist infinitely many distinct rational number $\dfrac{r}{s}$ such that $|\dfrac{a}{b}-\dfrac{r}{s}|\leq \dfrac{1}{s}$.

My incomplete working:
If $\dfrac{a}{b}$ is in reduced form then $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Therefore, there exist integers $r$ and $s$ such that $as +(-r)b = 1$.
Dividing both sides by $bs$ gives $\dfrac{a}{b}-\dfrac{r}{s} = \dfrac{1}{bs}$.
Taking absolute value on both sides gives
$$\bigg|\dfrac{a}{b}-\dfrac{r}{s}\bigg| \leq \bigg|\dfrac{1}{bs}\bigg| = \dfrac{1}{|b||s|}$$.
Thus, $|\dfrac{a}{b}-\dfrac{r}{s}| \leq \dfrac{1}{|s|}$  because $|b| > 1$.
or $|\dfrac{a}{b}-\dfrac{r}{s}| \leq \dfrac{1}{s}$.
My question is:
**How to prove the existence of infinitely many distinct rational numbers $\dfrac{r}{s}$?**

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $a(s+bk)-b(r+ak)=1.$

Comment: Could I have some explanation / hints about this equation?

Comment: Hint: Anne's equation holds for infinitely many $k$. Then take $s_k=s+bk$ and $r_k=r+ak$ and plug that into the equations/inequalities you already have.